# When to expect increment to add 2?

Tags: syntax

I expected `3` from both of these

```
j = 2; new = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}; new[[++j]] += 2; j
j = 2; new = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}; new[[++j]] = 2; j
```

> 4
>   3

Why does the first one return 4?

Comment: *Mathematica* is not a programming language like C. It is a system for rewriting expressions. Some rewrites imitate conventional procedural programming constructs, but be wary. Usually, there are better ways to do what you want.

Comment: Note that your first line of code increments the 4th element of `list`, not the 3rd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's really a nasty one. I don't think that it is supposed to work this way, but apparently,

```
new[[++j]] += 2
```

is equivalent to

```
new[[++j]] = new[[++j]] + 2
```

That's why `++j` gets executed twice.

I am not sure, but maybe `AddTo` is implemented as follows:

```
SetAttributes[addto, HoldFirst];
addto[a_, b_] := a = a + b;
```

Since the first argument is held, `new[[++j]]` is evaluated twice under execution of `addto[new[[++j]],2]`.

Comment: Both `AddTo` and `PreIncrement` have the attribute `HoldFirst`

Comment: My uncertainty about the implementation was more about the true internals than about the fact that `AddTo` has that attribute. In principle, the held expression could be analyzed for occurences of `Part` and this behavior could be prevented by enforcing that the second arguments of `Part` get evaluated only once.